# How to see what methods are being used in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Hey just wondering if I ran my program could Eclipse show me how much each method is being used?

Comment: Yes. Use the [debugger](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecbug/index.html) (or [video tutorials](http://eclipsetutorial.sourceforge.net/debugger.html)). Or is this a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713940/eclipse-java-profiler)?

Comment: What do you mean by how much? Is it how many calls are there to the method? how much time is taking to execute the method?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for a profiler that tells you which parts of your code  is being exercised?